# Tips on encryption/decryption of images in java using AES

Tags: java

I need help regarding some ideas for encryption and decryption of images.

I want to encrypt/ decrypt the images and use them to prevent unauthorized users from substituting my images with their ones. I have the code for encryption/ decryption with AES. However, I am confused when to decrypt the images and how to determine which encrypted byte array belongs to a particular image. I want to use 2d byte array for this. Anybody having any ideas, on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-** Well i would ask you to use `Cipher`, `CipherInputStream` and `CipherOutputStream` for **encryption** and **decryption**.

**-** You can use this on images, files, videos, etc...

**See this link :**

http://www.flexiprovider.de/examples/ExampleCrypt.html