# Encrypting files with AES on Android

Tags: java, android, encryption

So I am working on a personal project for myself, and I am trying to encrypt files on my phone. These files can be anything i.e Documents, photos, etc. Right now I am trying to get this working properly. When ever I run the encryption it seems to work properly and encrypt the files. When I run the decrypt, sometimes it works and other times it doesn't. When it fails I generally get a "Error while finalizing cipher, pad block corrupted" error. I'm also not using different test files, so it isn't like some files work and others don't. It's the same two files I try each time.

```
public static void encryptfile(String path,String Pass) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.concat(".crypt"));
    byte[] key = (salt + Pass).getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key,16);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fis.close();
}

public static void decrypt(String path,String Pass) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.replace(".crypt",""));
    byte[] key = (salt + Pass).getBytes("UTF-8");
    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    key = sha.digest(key);
    key = Arrays.copyOf(key,16);
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
        fos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();
    cis.close();
}
```

Currently the Salt and Password are static and do not change for testing purposes. Still get errors about half the time.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this happens? I have been searching around and I have found a couple things to try, none of which worked. I have looked through some of the following questions for solutions:

[Android decryption: Error while finalizing cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426151/android-decryption-error-while-finalizing-cipher)

[last block incomplete with CipherInputStream/CipherOutputStream, even with padding AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799726/last-block-incomplete-with-cipherinputstream-cipheroutputstream-even-with-paddi)

[Encryption error on Android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383006/encryption-error-on-android-4-2)

[Decrypting error : "no iv set when one expected"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503157/decrypting-error-no-iv-set-when-one-expected)

[How to handle "last block incomplete in decryption"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598873/how-to-handle-last-block-incomplete-in-decryption)

[Encryption and decryption of image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136558/encryption-and-decryption-of-image-file)

[Tips on encryption/decryption of images in java using AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527521/tips-on-encryption-decryption-of-images-in-java-using-aes)

Any help is greatly appreciated! I think I am just missing something simple...

Update!

People were right when it was the salt. When I removed the salt, the problem was solved... Did a little more digging, turns out salt+Pass was the issues, but because the salt was a byte[] and Pass was a string. I changed salt to String and then used salt.concat(Pass) and the problem was solved!

Comment: I personally would be interested to see what you tried to implement. It could also help others as they can see which options have been tried (even if they were implemented incorrectly).

Comment: @Bono I have added links that I thought would be helpful to me, but ended up not helping me to much. I have tried things like making it so doesn't have padding, uses CBC instead of EBC (Which I would like to do anyways). At one point I even had it converting the Base64 :P

Comment: It seems like the salt is most likely the problem, as a salt consists of random bytes, but it is given as a string. How did you create the salt?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I wish it was, but the Salt is currently fixed for testing :/

Comment: This error could occur for wrong keys, garbled ciphertext or - only for pretty short ciphertext - because of a wrong IV value. If you enter the wrong password this will be the only way of detecting it (if no authentication tag is present).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes currently I'm just using set variables for the password and salt. This is so I can test the encryption and make sure I don't have those kinds of problems. I can double check this by logging the keys. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

maybe I'm missing something but on my side it works without a problem.
Can you try the following class simply changing the fileToBeCrypted, fileToBeDecrypted and fileDecryptedOutput variables?

```
package test;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class TestCrypt{

    private static final String salt = "t784";
    private static final String cryptPassword = "873147cbn9x5'2 79'79314";
    private static final String fileToBeCrypted = "c:\\Temp\\sampleFile.conf";
    private static final String fileToBeDecrypted = "c:\\Temp\\sampleFile.conf.crypt";
    private static final String fileDecryptedOutput = "c:\\Temp\\sampleFile.conf.decrypted";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            encryptfile(fileToBeCrypted, cryptPassword);
            decrypt(fileToBeDecrypted, cryptPassword, fileDecryptedOutput);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public static void encryptfile(String path,String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path.concat(".crypt"));
        byte[] key = (salt + password).getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key,16);
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
            cos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
    }

    public static void decrypt(String path,String password, String outPath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outPath);
        byte[] key = (salt + password).getBytes("UTF-8");
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key,16);
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);
        CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, cipher);
        int b;
        byte[] d = new byte[8];
        while((b = cis.read(d)) != -1) {
            fos.write(d, 0, b);
        }
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        cis.close();
    }

}
```

I can iterate many times without an error!
I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8 but running in 1.7 compatibility mode.

Hope this helps you out.

Bye
Piero

Comment: Turns out it was the salt....Only problem is I am not sure why. I am doing more digging :)

Comment: Agree with Linux, salt can´t contains special characters.

Comment: Not working for Video Files. After encryption and decryption, videos not playing. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Hi, there are no special configuration or changes to handle binary files like videos: where are you storing them?

Comment: Can we use any characters as salt?

Comment: Not only SALT can be created with any character but if you look at the code you see that SALT is used as byte array: that means SALT can be made of any byte array (so even with non printable chars like \r or \n).