# Downloading offline videos like hotstar

Tags: java, android, video, video-streaming, offline

I have an app which stream videos, now my new feature is to save that videos for offline view. I saw offline feature of hotstar, when we save offline video hotstar save video spit as some **chunk.ts** format, it will be saved on corresponding andriod folder of hotstar, how can i achive this I search web but did not get any proper info how to implment this. when I search for chunk.ts I got some github data https://github.com/AndyA/ts-split

which is in pearl, so when I saw I had doubt like this should done on serverside and when we download the files will downloaded from server.
can any one give an expert suggetion regarding this.

Thank you

Comment: why can't you just download the video (file) to the device directly?

Comment: i dont wanna others to copy or open video by there app or player

Comment: could you do something similar to what youtube does? they download the file as exo but encrypt it, so it won't be played by other media players, so i suggest you find a suitable encryption mechanism to your need, and download the video, then decrypt the file to play it, this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/114173) provides good insight that i suspect would help you get started

Comment: but how any clue to make it?

Comment: @SamwinishereHere hav you got the solution or created it??? i am looking for solution for offline video download, i am trying exoplayer .. but not able to create offline download feature.

Comment: there was a github repo of a user but he removed that one

Answer (score 0):

one way to achieve this would be to use a CipherOutputStream and encrypt the files as they are downloaded check [CipherOutputStream](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html)

also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115035/encrypting-files-with-aes-on-android) questions, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906218/encrypt-and-decrypt-files) question on how to encrypt and decrypt.
and for rendering the videos, you would have to decrypt the files as you play them