# Protect offline content

Tags: android

I'm creating a video club app in android studio, and wanted to put a resource for the user to view the movie offline as netflix does, but for security reasons I wanted to do something for the movie only to be read by APP but not I know how to do this, can recommend me sites to read on this subject, I already googled in google and I find nothing!

Comment: Encrypt the video and decrypt it in your video player app.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What have you tried? There are millions of articles about encryption on the web

Comment: A determined attacker will always be able to get at the video, outside your app. You can make it harder, but you can't make it impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look on this answer about file encryption with AES on Android to start [Encrypting files with AES on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115035/encrypting-files-with-aes-on-android)

Also, you may need to send decrypted bytes buffer straight to video player, not to actually create decrypted temp file.